# Keystore File Invalid Format (z/OS Unix System Services)

Tags: unix, keystore, zos

I am using a z/OS java jar which requires a keystore and truststore file.

I have FTP'd all of the files to the z/OS Unix directory(Mainframe).

When executing the jar, I receive an "invalid keystore file format" error.  When I use the keytool on my local machine on the keystore file, the command is successful.  When using the keytool command on the remote (zOS Unix), I am getting the format error.  The files are being transmitted in binary format.

Is there a particular way that I should be transmitting the file to MF Unix?

Comment: When you say FTP'd which mode did you use.  I assume binary?  If you used scp then the file was converted and not transferred correctly.  Use sftp or ftp with bin to ensure that the file is transmitted correctly

Comment: When you say a colleague transferred the keystone successfully using SCP, do you mean that the keystore works properly?  Can you open the keystore in a text editor?

Comment: I tried several other processes to upload and the result was still the same.  When I used SSH to connect to the host and used the keytool remotely, the format issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

There are three primary way I use to transfer files to z/OS USS depending on whether I want conversion or not (from utf-8 to ibm-1047 for instance).

With conversion:

- `scp` works and will translate the files characters while transferring.  Note: this is an IBM behaviour that you do not normally see when transferring from distributed system to distributed system.  It's really annoying.
- `ftp` with ascii mode

Without Conversion:

- `ftp` with transfer mode set to `binary`
- `sftp`

Choose the option that makes the most sense based on the client in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hogstrom.  Unfortunately, I have tried these steps.  I have used the remote host in IntelliJ and I have also used FTP/SFTP in FileZilla with binary mode and autodetect.  I am unfamiliar with scp(I am assuming you mean winScp).

I did have a colleague who used winScp successfully.  However, I am using a Mac and not sure if there is a version for MacOS.

Comment: I found the scp command within the Mac OS terminal.  Was able to upload the file but the results are the same with respect to the invalid format.

Comment: When you  ftp the file you are typing bin?   Since you are on mac OS did you use ncftp ?

Comment: I tried several other processes to upload and the result was still the same. When I used SSH to connect to the host and used the keytool remotely, the format issue was resolved